# Reset password recovery state

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

Here's the situation :

I have an ASP.NET PasswordRecovery (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.passwordrecovery.aspx) control used on my login page.

When I click on the "Recover link", it ask me for my username, I enter it, click the "Send my password" button, it notifies me that an email has been sent and then I can click on the "back" link to go back to the login control and proceed.

My problem is : If I click again on the "Recover link", the control is stuck in it's last state, which is the successful state or the failed state. If stuck in the successful state, the user won't be able to enter any username. Only the last successful message will be displayed, without being able to repeat the same procedure as before.

I would like to reset the PasswordRecovery control to it's initial state, so the user could do another password recovery operation without having to refresh the current page (hit F5).

I played a bit with the viewstate + destroy/recreate the control but without any success.

Anybody had this issue before?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So define an event for clicking the button.

Comment: Thanks but that's not helping. I am asking how to reset the control state, not how to handle a button click.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I validated that there is no clean way to do this (via ILSpy), see the example below for the slightly dirty way.  Basically we use reflection to get the `CurrentView` property, which is an internal property, then we set the current view of the PasswordReset control to one of the three possible states: Username (0), Question (1), or Success (2).

***Designer***

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:PasswordRecovery ID="pwr" runat="server"></asp:PasswordRecovery>
</div>
<span>Set Recover State: </span>
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblChangeState" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="rblChangeState_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Username" Value="0" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Question" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Success" Value="2" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
</form>
```

***Code Behind***

```
protected void rblChangeState_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Type t = pwr.GetType();
    PropertyInfo viewSetter = t.GetProperty("CurrentView", BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    viewSetter.SetValue(pwr, Convert.ToInt32(rblChangeState.SelectedValue), null);
}
```